# how could it be possible to have PTEs 4 bytes each and 4kb Pages at the same time for 32-bit virtual address space?

Tags: virtual-memory

how could it be possible to have PTEs 4 bytes each and 4kb Pages at the same time for 32-bit virtual address space?

I came across this example while studying virtual memory.

I think If we have 4KB Pages then we must have 12 offset bits(as VPO or PPO). Now, we have 20 bits left. So, How could it be possible to have PTEs with a size of 4bytes each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

Here is the story: PTEs don't carry VPN bits necessarily, the link between them is like this: we use VPN bits to compute the address of corresponding PTE. Base Pointer (PT adress of a specific process) + some of VPN bits (if we use one level page then we can use all of them)